# Auto-populate data

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, vlookup, dropdownlist

Tricky problem for me.

Is it possible to use a drop-down box (or alternate tool) to select a specific week, then use this to auto-populate data into a larger data table?

E.g.
step 1 - select week e.g. starting 22 July
2 - input variable data in 7 different cells i.e. mon - fri
3 - larger table auto-populated, and new data then pulled through again if that week re-selected using drop-down

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need add more info/details to your question, what you have tried also.

Comment: autopopulate, and new data imply needing VBA, if you are just filtering an existing data set based (the filtered data can show up on a different sheet) on the criteria in your dropdown, then formulas can be used.

Comment: It's possible, but you should provide more information and screenshots about your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.

You populate your dropdown with a Table or range having the weeks, to display however makes best sense to you. Best to fill that table with real date numbers to make the formulas for the columns easier, but if you don't mind the extra work, text will do fine.

The choice there populates a cell. You base the seven (or five... you contradict yourself) dates you want (or days of the week... you contradict yourself) on that date. For instance, you want Mon-Fri? 7-22 is a Thursday, so you you want that date minus 3, minus 2, minus 1, itself, and plus 1. Format those header cells as weekdays but leave the values as actual date numbers in case that's handy.

If you populated your dropdown's source Table or range with actual TEXT not date numbers, the columns will be slightly harder to fill as you will have to take apart the text string for the date elements and convert them to a date. THEN do the "minus 3 for Monday, etc." I show above.

Finally, you presumably have some formulas in mind for populating the data region. Perhaps `VLOOKUP()`, our old friend, will do the work based upon the column headers. However you plan to do that, do that.

If you change the input date, the data range will presumably change as the headers the lookups are based upon will change. So that's all good.

Your only difficulty would be if you have the fairly crazy intention to use any old dates in the dropdown, like 7-21, 7-22, 7-23, 7-24, etc. rather than one day of the week for every week of interest, like 7-22, 7-29, 8-5, 8-12. If you DO go with the any old date, there's no real reason for the dropdown, eh? Hence my believing you do not intend that.

But if you do, it's just harder. You'd have to take the date selected and use the `WEEKDAY()` function to find its day of the week, then subtract or add days accordingly in the column headers. Note that this is HARD to do if you just use brute force, but cleverness in using the function's options can make it just an annoying thing to have to also do.

The last consideration is that if you intend all this output to be a formal Excel Table, you're job just got harder **because Excel Tables CANNOT UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCE have anything except TEXT headers.**

So you wouldn't be able to dynamically change the headers for the columns like you seem to desire. Not the end of the world... you can still fill your data region with the right data for the date you select in the dropdown, it's just... what's the word I used before? HARDER.

So don't use a Table for this. Use a range. If you DO use a Table, pose another question here, specifying that and asking how to populate your data region with that limitation. You can also overcomplicate your formulas, with all that can entail, to make dynamic headers in the first row under the formal headers, if you desire. But separate question as that feels fairly above and beyond this one.

But... "of course you can" do things like this. They aren't actually complex or even complicated in practice or to understand. You just have to do a few to get the ideas down, then apply as needed for each particular set of concerns.